# How to use default style with datatriggers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have default styles set from MaterialDesignInXaml and when I try to add a datatrigger to the control it does not use that same style.

How do I still use the default style while having datatriggers?

```
<TextBox Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="5" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search">
       <TextBox.Style>
              <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"> <!--Not Allowed to do this -->
                  <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchStyle, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Search">
                            <Setter Property="Label.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                       </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>                       
        </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the exact [`TargetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.targettype?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Style.TargetType)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) for the `Style` that matches the base style.

> [...] if you create a style with a `TargetType` property and base it on another style that also defines a `TargetType` property, the target type of the derived style must be the same as or be derived from the target type of the base style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}">
```

In the [source code](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/24c6468b8e93211e1283ba4f4cf8765baa81486e/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L540), the `MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox` style has a `TextBox` target type.